# Android Studio for loop issue

Tags: java, android, loops, while-loop

```
    private static final String TAG = MainMenu.class.getSimpleName();
    Log.d(TAG, "begin loop");
    for (int fa = 0; fa < 2000; ++fa) {
        Log.d(TAG, "starting loop " + String.valueOf(fa));
        for (int fb = 0; fb < 8; ++fb) {
            Log.d(TAG, "fb = " + String.valueOf(fb));
        }
    }
```

I know this is a pretty simple nested loop.  I'm getting something screwy happening that for the life of me I can't see why.  I tried to rewrite it using a while loop, but the same thing happened.

Here is an example of the screwy things that is happening:

```
    D: starting loop 53
    D: fb = 0
    D: fb = 1
    D: fb = 2
    D: fb = 3
    D: fb = 4
    D: fb = 5
    D: fb = 6
    D: starting loop 54
    D: fb = 0
    D: fb = 2
    D: fb = 3
    D: fb = 4
    D: fb = 6
    D: starting loop 55
    D: fb = 0
    D: fb = 1
    D: fb = 3
    D: fb = 4
    D: fb = 6
    D: starting loop 56
    D: fb = 0
    D: fb = 1
    D: fb = 3
    D: fb = 4
    D: fb = 6
    D: fb = 7
    D: fb = 0
    D: fb = 1
    D: fb = 3
    D: fb = 4
    D: fb = 6
    D: fb = 7
```

I put the first log statement so that I would know if it was being ran in another thread and somehow getting the pointers reset, but in the log there is only one "begin loop".

You can see in loop 53, it doesn't even make it to 7, in loop 54 and 55 it skips numbers and in 56 it starts back over again.

Is this an issue with rows not being logged or is it an issue with looping?

I tried commenting out the inner Log and I get output like this:

```
    D: starting loop 1642
    D: starting loop 1643
    D: starting loop 1645
    D: starting loop 1646
    D: starting loop 1647
    D: starting loop 1649
    D: starting loop 1650
    D: starting loop 1652
```

You can see that it is skipping numbers.  I'm hoping that this is just a logging issue and there isn't some big issue with for loops.

Any help anyone can give is greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like async logging. You don't mention what logged you're using. What happens if you replace the logs with `System.out.println`?

Comment: Unrelated: fa/fb are **very** uncommon names for loop counters. Use i, j, k ... instead. And do i++; not ++i. That is also very uncommon. Thing: you do NOT want to surprise your readers with such stuff. It makes it 10 times harder to read your code when you deviate from common practices.

Comment: I made it those weird variables for a point.  To make is obvious that those variables aren't being used somewhere else.  I know if I declare the variable in the loop start then it's local, but I wanted to make it obvious.

Comment: trying the System.out.println now.

Comment: Get the same issue when using System.out.println


        I: starting loop 1709

        I: starting loop 1710

        I: starting loop 1712

        I: starting loop 1713

        I: starting loop 1714

        I: starting loop 1716

        I: starting loop 1717

Comment: Fix : Thread.sleep(50) before the inner loop starts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work, but it doesn't. Why you ask? I don't think its anything related to your code, but more to Console IO. You're writing 18001 lines in some (milli)seconds, this can just go wrong :D
Try to add some sleeps in iterations, or just print less
Happy Coding!

Comment: just use the `System.out.println()` instead of `Log.d()`

Comment: That is what I was hoping.  I will test with a sleep at the end of each inner loop then.

Comment: system.out.println() gives same issue.  trying to put sleep in inner loop now

Comment: Glad it helped!